# In Amazon AppStream, how do I determine the Fleet ID for a Fleet?

Tags: .net, aws-appstream

I'm using the Amazon SDK to determine information about instances in a Fleet.  When creating a DescribeFleetsRequest, I am supposed to pass in a list of Fleet IDs.  But I cannot find any reference to a Fleet ID in my AWS console.  Where would I get this information from?  Here's my code, with the ???? representing what I cannot find in the AWS Console.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
using Amazon;
using Amazon.EC2;
using Amazon.EC2.Model;

namespace AppStreamTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var accessKeyId = "yyyyyyyy";
            var secretAccessKey = "xxxxxxx";
            var regionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1; // Replace with the region endpoint you want to use

            var ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, regionEndpoint);

            var request = new DescribeFleetsRequest
            {
                FleetIds = new List<string> { "????????" } //what do I use here?
            };

            var response = ec2Client.DescribeFleetsAsync(request);

            foreach (var fleetData in response.Result.Fleets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Fleet ID: {fleetData.FleetId}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Fleet State: {fleetData.ActivityStatus}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Number of Instances: {fleetData.Instances.Count}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Fleet Name does not work, I've already tried.)

EDIT: it looks like FleetID is no longer part of an AWS AppStream Fleet object.  When asked, ChatGPT was insisting FleetID was an important identifier, but its training data is over a year old.

Answer (score 0):

FleetIDs are apparently no longer used as identifiers for Fleets in Amazon AWS AppStream. I was apparently looking at older documentation, which led me to expect FleetIDs.